# Set and store QGIS master authentication password with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, authentication

In a fresh QGIS installation I would like to set the master authentication password and store it in the password manager using PyQGIS (e.g. in a startup script).

The method `QgsAuthManager.setMasterPassword('some_password')` sets the password but does not store it in the password manager. Thus, with the next QGIS start I'm prompted to enter the password and can opt to store it (default):

[image]

Is there a way to set and store the master password in one step via PyQGIS authentication API?